# Getting an error when I visit http://localhost

Tags: php, apache, localhost

I am trying to access localhost on my xampp via the Chrome browser but I get this error message:

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the 
URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404
```

Apache and MySQL are turned on so I don't understand.

Comment: Maybe try to create a regular html file called test.html in one of your vhosts that is not working. Then try to visit that url. That should give you some clue as to what may be the problem.

Comment: You can get this error if filename extensions are turned off so you accidentally create a file called `index.php.txt` which will not be found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access "localhost" just fine.

The "404: file not found" error indicates the server can't find the requested file once you've *connected* to localhost.

ADDENDUM:

> Maybe try to create a regular html file called test.html in one of
>   your vhosts that is not working. Then try to visit that url. That
>   should give you some clue as to what may be the problem. – Gohn67

This is good advice.  Try it.  Specifically:

1) Create the following five files:

- C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host.localhost/test.html
- C:/xampp/htdocs/my/test.html
- C:/xampp/htdocs/launcher/public_html/test.html
- C:/xampp/htdocs/website/httpdocs/test.html
- C:/xampp/htdocs/my/test.html

2) Make sure each of these directories exist, and each has a "test.html" with the words "TESTING 1...2...3" in it

3) Try each of these five URLs in your browser:

- http://localhost/test.html
- http://itutormaths.web/test.html
- http://itutormaths.mod/test.html
- http://itutormaths.hub/test.html
- http://my.itm/test.html

4) Report back the exact error you get from each browser URL

Comment: I don't understand. I should be able to access the other URLs but I can't =/

Comment: I have wordpress installed as well but I can't access that

Answer (score 1):

Navigate here:

```
http://localhost/
```

If that works, everything is okay.

Paste wordpress to `xampp/htdocs`, and you should not get any error.

Comment: :((( But on other browsers does????? You said this problem only goes for Chrome - or does for every browser???

Comment: Anyway if that goes for EVERY browser (no tonly Chrome), I would recommend for you to uninstal xammps, restart PC and then install again without touching anything (especially dont touch folder where xampps wants to be installed). Then try upper link again and give us a call. If that aint gonna work, uninstall again, restart, try to download lower version of xammps like 1.5.1 best and install that one :P Good luck ;)

Comment: @Xfile - I think the OP meant he happens to be using Chrome ... but the problem is that one virtual domain works, the others don't.  I'm certain if he tries my suggestion above, he'll resolve the problem.  My guess is he probably doesn't have a default "index.html" in the other directories, and/or the directory names are incorrect in his DocumentRoot clause.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and this is how I resolved it:

1. Open the httpd:conf file on the Apache module in XAMPP (click the Congif button)
2. Scroll through the file - after the first set of comments (#) there is a line of code which says 'Listen 80'.  Change this to 81 (or whatever other port you want to use).
3. Open web browser and explicitly define the port in the web address:

   127.0.0.1:81

The may or may work for you; I initially had the issue that Apache wouldn't start at all, which is why I changed the port number (couldn't be bothered to figure out which service was using port 80 - if you want to you can use the command netstats -a or netstats -b in command prompt to figure it out)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this and solve this by creating .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /yourfoldername/
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```